# Jsoup: null result in absUrl (abs:)

Tags: java, uri, jsoup

I tried to make a image links downloader with jsoup. I have made a downloader HTML code part, and when I have done a parse part, I recognized, that sometimes links to images appeared without main part. So I found absUrl solution, but by some reasons it did not work (it gave me null). So I tried use `uri.resolve()`, but it gave me unchanged result. So now I do not know how to solve it. I attached part of my code, that responsible for parsing ant writing url to string:

```
public static String finalcode(String textin) throws Exception {
    String text = source(textin);
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text);
    Elements images = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
    String Simages = images.toString();
    int Limages = countLines(Simages);
    StringBuilder src = new StringBuilder();
    while (Limages > 0) {
        Limages--;
        Element image = images.get(Limages);
        String href = image.attr("src");
        src.append(href);
        src.append("\n");
    }
    String result = src.toString();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are parsing HTML from String, not from URL. Because of that jsoup can't know from which URL this HTML comes from, so it can't create absolute path.

To set this URL for Document you can parse it using [`Jsoup.parse(String html, String baseUri)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) version, like

```
String url = "http://server/pages/document.htlm";
String text = "<img src = '../images/image_name1.jpg'/><img src = '../images/image_name2.jpg'/>'";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(text, url);
Elements images = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element image : images){
    System.out.println(image.attr("src")+" -> "+image.attr("abs:src"));
}
```

Output:

```
../images/image_name1.jpg -> http://server/images/image_name1.jpg
../images/image_name2.jpg -> http://server/images/image_name2.jpg
```

---

Other option would be letting Jsoup parse page directly by supplying URL instead of String with HTML

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").get();
```

This way Document will know from which URL it came, so it will be able to create absolute paths.